# Can't pass variable using Javascript toggle to form input

Tags: javascript, php, html, date

I am trying to pass "selecteddate", which is a selected date from a menu, with the variables that follow using this:

```
<a class="addlink" href="javascript:togglevis(\'addform\',\'selecteddate='.$day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year.'\');">Add date</a>
```

into a form with the following input:

```
<input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" class="standard" onchange="document.getElementById('startdate').value = this.value" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['selecteddate'])) { echo str_replace('-','/',$_GET['selecteddate']); } else { echo date("j/m/Y",mktime()); } ?>" />
```

The form toggle's and everything works, except it always grabs the current date from the else statement. I'm relatively certain that the selected date is not coming through, if I remove the else statement I just end up with an empty text box. Any suggestions as how I should format the addlink to send the selected date into the form? Thanks for any assistance, first time poster and have solved a lot of problems just from searching around this site, certainly a great resource!

Comment: please format your code for readability

Answer (score -1):

> `<input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" class="standard" onchange="document.getElementById('startdate').value = this.value" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['selecteddate'])) { echo str_replace('-','/',$_GET['selecteddate']); } else { echo date("j/m/Y",mktime()); } ?>" />`

From what I'm understanding attempting to call PHP AFTER the page has been loaded. Do keep in mind that all PHP code is called before the page is rendered in the browser. So when the page is rendered you're going to end up with:

> `<input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" class="standard" onchange="document.getElementById('startdate').value = this.value" value="<? date("j/m/Y",mktime());) ?>" />`

I don't have any further answer because I don't fully follow what you've got already/trying to do with it, but hopefully this helps!

Also! When you're testing your code, if you're always getting the else from an if statement, it usually means the element you're attempting to check doesn't exist yet. Try doing a `var_dump()` on your variables when you run into that problem.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, all the PHP is called on the page load. There's no attempt to call PHP post page load (which is impossible, without an XHR).

Comment: @SterlingArcher It used to be common to POST to the current page. GET request would return different content than a POST request.

Comment: @Ngz that's called a sticky form. Either way, get or post, this is not an attempt to run PHP after the page is finished loading. The javascript does not alter the URL params. It is simply checking if the get value is set, and if so, run a string replace.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Gotcha, yeah just not sure what togglevis() is doing. But you're right, there is no attempt to execute PHP after load.

Comment: var_dump($_GET['selecteddate']) returns null, but works in other parts. @SCHULTZ You would be correct the page renders exactly like you are saying, except as is pointed out the replace will replace any dashes with slashes and no php is being executed. What togglevis is doing is toggling another page, an add form. It's almost like a popup, but it scrolls down on the open page, more or less an effect. Anyhow the selecteddate works in other parts of the code, but for whatever reason is not working here, and I'm hoping to find a way to pass selecteddate into the form by adding it in the href link.